# IE doesn't have response.data from /me/friends

Tags: jquery, facebook, each

I'm not sure if I have to ask about jQuery or about Facebook, but so :
My current website [Social Promo](http://www.social-promo.fr) allows users to invite their friends to join for sponsoring. So I use the code below, and it works fine... except on IE.

```js
function load_friends() {
    if($('#fb_friendbox').is(':empty')) {
        FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
            $.each(response.data, function(index,friend) {
                var nextFriend = '<div class="fb_friend" onclick="resend_invite('+friend.id+');return false;"><div class="fb_picture"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+ friend.id +'/picture" /></div><div class="fb_name"><span>'+ friend.name +'</span></div></div>';
                $('#fb_friendbox').append(nextFriend);
            });
            $('.ajax-load').css('display','none');
        });
    }
}
```

IE's js console tells me (from french) `Can't get value of 'length', object is null or undefined`. So as I don't use IE often (and as far as I know, I can't use a console.log or debug), I just tried some alert() and see :

- `response` is an object
- `response.data` is undefined (others browsers, like Chrome, return me a list of objects)
- The code flow is fine until the `$.each` line

So at the end, IE don't load the list of friends of the current user, and I don't know what. Did I missed something in this function IE needs but not others browsers ?

Comment: I don't know... maybe 31% of my visitors (IE8&9) ? After all, Facebook cares about IE from 6 to 9.

Comment: You _can_ use console in IE, at least in IE9. Press `F12` to open the developer tools. That also has debug capabilities.

Comment: I know about console on IE8&9, I mean `console.debug` and `console.log` commands, telling more than an classic alert(var). I use it on Chrome and Firefox, I was disappointed  IE doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I’d *bet* that response.error is set, and is telling you that you’re not using a valid access token.

And that, I’m also quite sure, again stems from the age-old *third party cookies* problem …

Answer (score 0):

Annnd... closed. My problem is solved, and in fact it never existed. I'm working with Linux, so for IE version I borrowed a colleague's Windows pc and finally discovered (by trying on another colleague's pc, and everything worked fine) the first one blocks every Facebook request in a way I don't understand, nor what is doing this behavior. That's with `data` and `error` didn't existed.